# PHP file upload issue on SUSE

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, suse

I'm having a weird problem with file uploads with Apache/PHP 5.3 on a SLES 11 SP2
When I try to upload a file PHP only pick up the files original name (`$_FILES['name']`), and not all the other vars I need.

I have checked and double cheched my `php.ini` both for upload max file, put max size, file upload enabled etc.

Does anybody have an idea what is going on?

Here is the script I used to test it:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES)) {
    var_dump($_FILES);
}
?>
<!-- The data encoding type, enctype, MUST be specified as below -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

And this is what I receive:

```
array(1) { ["userfile"]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(8) "test.txt" } }
```

Comment: All I can reasonably suggest is you restart your server and try again.

Comment: Then please check Apache's error log.

Comment: Right now i do not have access to the server. I will check the logs once i get access. Anything in particular i should look for?

Comment: I have the exact same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908936/php-upload-file-only-filesname-is-populating. Is your machine a standard AMI in AWS, by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I had issue with $_FILES. It didnt upload any files.

I upgraded php components from 5.3.8-0.19.6 to 5.3.8-0.33.2 and worked...

[See this post](https://jira.ez.no/browse/EZP-19875)

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue writing the uploaded file to the tmp dir. What does `upload_tmp_dir` say in `phpinfo()`?

EDIT:

I see *No value* for `upload_tmp_dir`.  It may default to /tmp, but I would explicitly set it to /tmp in php.ini and check that you have set the permissions appropriately.  Setting `error_reporting` to On in conjunction with looking at your Apache logs would helpful in troubleshooting.  Since you don't have server access, you could try this directly in your php script:

```
ini_set('upload_tmp_dir', '/tmp')
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: The upload_tmp_dir says '/tmp' and the folder is there .Here is the link for phpinfo http://173.14.125.3/sourcefirst/php_info.php

Comment: This is the output i get when i print_r the $_FILE variable, i have also added the code you sent me  Array ( [uploaded_cv] => Array ( [name] => changes11.doc ) )

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with PHP upload in SLES 11 SP2. In our case the `/tmp` folder limit was max out.

Try `df -h` command to see if you need some cleaning.