# PHP upload file - only $_FILES['name'] is populating

Tags: php

I've been scouring the internet for two days with this problem, hopefully someone else has ran across this before. I see a lot of questions on S.O. about file uploads and PHP, but my issue is slightly different. I'm hoping that I'm just missing something very obvious.

It appears as though the data from my form never reaches the server fully because the only parameter populated in the **$_FILES** array is 'name'.

For example, here is a vardump of **$_FILES**:

```
array(1) { ["gameimage"]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(15) "Donkey-kong.gif" } }
```

No **error code**, no **tmp_name**, and no **type** are present.

Here is some very basic HTML I'm testing with:

```
<form name="upload-image-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
<input type="file" name="gameimage" size="30" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here are my relevant php.ini settings:

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_file_uploads = 10
upload_tmp_dir is default, but I have tried with /tmp as well.
```

Running PHP 5.3.8

My suspicion is that apache mod_rewrite or some other apache mod is interferring.

I have full control of the host machine, it's a micro-instance running in AWS.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Amendment #1:**

I have verified from the browser console in Chrome and FF that data is transferring over http properly. My test files were very small, less than 10kb.

**Amendment #2:**

It seems as if someone else, with the exact same AWS instance, is running into the same problem:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/4452298.htm

There seems to be some core issue with these versions of apache and linux.

Comment: use print_r($_FILES) to see what is coming

Comment: I did a vardump, as I explained above.

Comment: Have you checked, if you see the data when submitting? Like in the chrome console?

Comment: How is your `post_max_size` setting in php.ini?that setting can not be too small if you want to upload a big file.

Comment: I don't think 2M in your php.ini equates to 2000000. You might want to try setting MAX_FILE_SIZE to 2097152

Comment: Have you tried running your code on a different server? I've seen this problem occur before and it was a problem do with the PHP installation.

Comment: I had faced a similar problem in the past. My issue was that "upload_tmp_dir" was'nt set properly. But it looks yours is.

Comment: Access rights (for the php user) in the temp dir. The 2M size is before encoding - the file transferred can be ~150% of its actual size. Try with a small file.

Comment: I did verify that the data is submitting properly over http in the browser console. I also was testing with a very small .gif file, around 6kb.

Comment: Yes. In fact, I borrowed the code from a different application I wrote. However, the code I am implementing here is so generic that it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: have you checked for the file permission for that directory where you are trying to keep the file? make it 777 & try again.

Comment: Is there something else doing security? Maybe suhosin? Did you check the config of that one?

Comment: I think your problem is temporary upload folder permission. Have you tried to use "move_upload_files" function?