# PHP $_FILES superglobal only containing name

Tags: php, file-upload

I've checked all over, including links like:
 
http://getluky.net/2004/10/04/apachephp-_files-array-mysteriously-empty/
[PHP upload file - only $_FILES['name'] is populating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908936/php-upload-file-only-filesname-is-populating)

Etc and tried all the suggestions but to no avail. 
I've even went the the extent of var_dumping the $_POST and $_FILES:

```
array(1) { 'description' => string(11) "finaldemand" }

array(1) {
  'file' =>
  array(5) {
    'name' =>
    string(16) "finaldemand.docx"
    'type' =>
    string(0) ""
    'tmp_name' =>
    string(0) ""
    'error' =>
    int(6)
    'size' =>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

It looks like the file is not being submitted at all, although my HTML (and I have tried various others) seems right:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="addTemplateScript.php" method="POST">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Choose a file to upload:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Used as:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="description" id="transfer" value="transfer" />Application to Transfer<br />
                        <input type="radio" name="description" id="lay" value="lay" />Application to Lay a Mooring<br />           
                    </td>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Upload file">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Where this script checks if it is a .docx and puts all the data into variables (a bit too large including PDO so I trimmed that):

```
<?php
include("includes/session.php");
var_dump($_POST);
// Check if a file has been uploaded
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    echo "<pre>";var_dump($_FILES);echo "</pre>";
        // Connect to the database
        $database = $functions->pdoConnect();

        // Gather all required data
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $mime = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $data = file_get_contents($_FILES  ['file']['tmp_name']);
        $size = intval($_FILES['file']['size']);
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        if ($mime != "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") {
            die("The file was not a .docx! Upload was cancelled.");
        }
```

Is there something which may be interfering? Is there a bug I should be aware of? 
**EDIT: **
I am running PHP 5.5.6 if it helps

Comment: Does PHP requre a temporary folder if the file's data is just being placed in a MySQL table?

Comment: Yes, a temp folder is required, check your php.ini and see if upload_tmp_dir is defined properly and have the rights perms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
$_FILES['file']['error'] = 6;
```

This means: UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR. Check if your tmp dir is existing and writeable by user from which is php running.

Answer (score -2):

@Greshnik

Not quite...

```
$_FILES['file']['error'] = int(6); // This has a NULL value.
```

The int(6) is not a value, but a data format, like...

```
$_FILES['file']['name'] = string(16) "finaldemand.docx"; // See value in quotes at end

$_FILES['file']['type'] = string(0) ""; // Value again in quotes

$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = string(0) ""; // Value again in quotes

$_FILES['file']['size'] = int(0); // Another one with a NULL value
```

Comment: int(6) in PHP notation means: Integer variable with value of 6.